# Installing Mali driver on ODROID-XU3 with ArchLinux

Tags: linux, driver, archlinux, odroid, mali

I have an ODROID-XU3 board with an ARM Mali T628. The board is running Arch Linux, with kernel version 3.4.104-2. I don't have the Mali drivers and I was wondering what the best way to install them would be. I'll be looking to run OpenCL applications on it, so if there is anything else that I need I would appreciate if you let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to find the tutorial? I've got the same problem..

Comment: No, I ended up flashing Ubuntu which had the Mali drivers pre-installed. This might be a good starting place though: http://forum.odroid.com/